# How to obtain certain lines from a text file in c#?

Tags: c#, string, file

I'm working in C# and i got a large text file (75MB)
I want to save lines that match a regular expression

I tried reading the file with a streamreader and ReadToEnd, but it takes 400MB of ram

and when used again creates an out of memory exception.

I then tried using File.ReadAllLines():

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("file");

StringBuilder specialLines = new StringBuilder();


foreach (string line in lines)

 if (match reg exp)

  specialLines.append(line);
```

this is all great but when my function ends the memory taken doesnt clear and I'm
left with 300MB of used memory, only when recalling the function and executing the line:
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("file");
I see the memory clearing down to 50MB give or take and then reallocating back to 200MB

How can I clear this memory or get the lines I need in a different way ?

Answer (score 6):

```
        var file = File.OpenRead("myfile.txt");
        var reader = new StreamReader(file);
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            string line = reader.ReadLine();
            //evaluate the line here.
        }
        reader.Dispose();
        file.Dispose();
```

Comment: Also, don't forget to dispose of the `FileStream` and `StreamReader` objects.

Comment: You don't need to create the stream yourself, the StreamReader constructor can take the file name directly. Also, you shouldn't use EndOfStream to check whether you're at the end of the file: since the StreamReader is buffering the data, the stream position could be at the end before the StreamReader returned all lines

Comment: You'd want to change that loop to: while(reader.Peek() >-1) {
  string line = reader.ReadLine(); //etc }
Instead of using !reader.EndOfStream, for the reasons Thomas mentioned.

Comment: And you should use `using` blocks, otherwise the file won't be closed if an exception occurs before the call to Dispose is reached

Answer (score 2):

You need to stream the text instead of loading the whole file in memory. Here's a way to do it, using an extension method and Linq:

```
static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateLines(this TextReader reader)
    {
        string line;
        while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            yield return line;
        }
    }
}

...

var regex = new Regex(..., RegexOptions.Compiled);
using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileName))
{
    var specialLines =
        reader.EnumerateLines()
              .Where(line => regex.IsMatch(line))
              .Aggregate(new StringBuilder(),
                         (sb, line) => sb.AppendLine(line));
}
```

Comment: +1 - I would throw in a notice that .NET 4.0 has a similar method already implemented.

Comment: @ChaosPandion, do you mean `File.ReadLines` ? Good to now, I never noticed it before...

Comment: That's correct. In retrospect I probably should have mentioned it. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [StreamReader#ReadLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx) to read file line-by-line and to save those lines that you need.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Enumerator pattern to keep your memory footprint low in case your file can be huge.